# How to disable the header ToC of a beamer document while still maintain its bookmarks?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, bookmarks

I would like to remove the ToC because it could occupy too much of space when number of sections become too large. However, I still want to use `\section` commands because they allow me to easily navigate my presentation as I prepare it. Is there a way to remove the ToC but not the bookmarks from a beamer document?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=1cm, sidebar width right=1cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5mm, text margin right=0.5mm}

\usepackage[square, nonamebreak, sort&compress, comma, numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Sections in ToC}

\blindtext[3]

\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Sections in ToC}

\blindtext[3]

\end{frame}


\section{Section 3}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Sections in ToC}

\blindtext[3]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headline navigation is introduced by the `split` theme you load. If you don't want it either not load this theme or redefine the headline template.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=1cm, sidebar width right=1cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5mm, text margin right=0.5mm}

\usepackage[square, nonamebreak, sort&compress, comma, numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Sections in ToC}

\blindtext[3]

\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Sections in ToC}

\blindtext[3]

\end{frame}


\section{Section 3}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Sections in ToC}

\blindtext[3]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just want to add that this command `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` should be just above `\begin{document}` to avoid being invalidated by other theme setting commands.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
```

and you can do the same for the bottom:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
```

No need to choose a different overall style. You can also wrap a section in `{`...`}` with those commands inside, in order to make the effect temporary.